# ALASQL: How to reference the JSON object it self (to call a function on it)?

Tags: alasql

I have the following object and I would like to call it's function.

```
[{a:1, fn:function(){} }]
```

Now I know if the object would be nested (`[{a:1, b:{fn:function(){} } }]`) that I could do `b->fn()` but how do I do it when it's direct property of the first element?

I tried just `SELECT fn() FROM ...` but that gives `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,` (so not a proper parser error).

Comment: Have you tried select fn FROM (no parens)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use _ variable. This is a pseudo-variable, which includes the record whole itself:

```
SELECT _->fn() FROM ...
```

You can see this [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/agershun/ws0vewj0/5/).